# How to hide UITableviewCell if it cannot be edited?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have a `UITableView` show as below. All cells in the tableview can be edited except the last one.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

[image: the tableview]

[image]

The first picture shows the tableview in normal mode; the second shows the tableview in editing mode. I do not want the last cell to be editable, so I return `false` in the function. But I do not want the last cell to appear when the tableview is in editing mode. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.[TableViewName].dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainOfThecell") as? UITableViewCell
   if [tableViewName].editing == true {

      if cell.editing == false {
            cell.hidden = true 
        } 
    } 
     return cell
   }
```

---

Explanation :

`[tableViewName].editing` => This will return a bool on whether the tableView is in editing mode
     `cell.editing` => This will return a bool on whether the cell is in edit editable state or not 
 If the return is `false` then `cell.hidden = true`  will hide the cell from the tableView.

NOTE:

When the user clicks in the button to edit the table execute `[tableViewName.reloadData()]` to force `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be executed

If you want only the last cell to be hidden then check for the `indexPath.row` of the cell to determine it's position

Comment: It does not work. if cell.editing == false {
        cell.hidden = true 
    } It will hide all the cell when the tableview is not on editing mode.